# TFS 2010 remote access

Tags: remote-access, team-foundation-server

Does anyone know if remote access to TFS 2010 is the same as for existing versions of TFS?
The latest documentation I have found is [Chapter 17 – Providing Internet Access to Team Foundation Server](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%2017%20-%20Providing%20Internet%20Access%20to%20Team%20Foundation%20Server&ProjectName=tfsguide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is old, but it was never marked as answered and there was never an appropriate answer directly to the question...

I believe what you mean by remote access is what is called Web Access.  Web Access is a web-based user interface for TFS that enables you to work with work items and builds. This tool has changed over time; This TFS component was initially developed by another company and was a seperate  install;  it was named *TeamPlain* at the time; then Microsoft purchased TeamPlain and released it as a Power Tool. This became Web Access and was still available as a seperate install in TFS 2008.

With the release of TFS 2010 in April of 2010, the Web Access power tool was integrated into TFS and was no longer a seperate install; installing TFS installs the Web Access tool into IIS on the server where TFS 2010 is installed and it can be accessed using pretty much the same address as TFS 2010, which is by default:  *http://:8080/tfs/web*

In TFS 2012, the Web Access component is taking on an even greater role with enhanced capabilities and improved performance.  It is still available at the same address and the user interface has undergone a major change as Microsoft has implemented Metro styling and additional tools and pages to manage Agile projects and in particular, Scrum - including a customizable summary dashboard-type screen, Product and Spring backlog management screens, an interactive Task board and real-time burdown charts.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following options paper:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ablock/attachment/9882725.ashx

Comment: That link is failing with an error page for me

Answer (score 0):

http://tfspreview.com/

Microsoft offers a hosted TFS service. Check it out. You need a code to get started, but it shouldn't take too long to have it sent out. Good luck!